# why is Model.all different to Model.where('true') in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a query, which works fine:

```
ModelName.where('true')
```

I can chain this with other AR calls such as where, order etc. However when I use:

```
ModelName.all
```

I receive the "same" response but can't chain a where or order to it as it's an array rather than a AR collection.
Whereas I have no pragmatic problem using the first method it seems a bit ugly/unnecessary. Is there a cleaner way of doing this maybe a .to_active_record_collection or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an easy solution. Instead of using

```
ModelName.where('true')
```

Use:

```
ModelName.scoped
```

Comment: ah! didn't understand that was what you needed :)

Comment: In Rails 4.2.x, both ModelName.scoped and ModelName.where(true) have been forbidden.  Now if you have ModelName.all in your legacy code, you get an AR-Relation instead of the Array you were expecting.  And if you have ModelName.where(true) or ModelName.scoped in your existing code, you now get an error that crashes your app.  Many improvements need to be made, but instead, time is spent breaking syntax that works.

Answer (score 3):

As you said:

```
ModelName.where('true').class #=> ActiveRecord::Relation

ModelName.all.class #=> Array
```

So you can make as many lazy loading as long as you don't use `all`, `first` or `last` which trigger the query.

It's important to catch these differences when you consider caching.

Still I can't understand what kind of situation could lead you to something like:

```
ModelName.all.where(foobar)
```

... Unless you need the whole bunch of assets for one purpose and get it loaded from the database and need a subset of it to other purposes. For this kind of situation, you'd need to use ruby's Array filtering methods.

---

Sidenote:

```
 ModelName.all
```

should never be used, it's an anti-pattern since you don' control how many items you'll retrieve. And hopefully:

```
 ModelName.limit(20).class #=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the latter returns an array of elements, while the former is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You can order and filter array using Ruby methods. For example, to sort by id you can call `sort_by(&:id)`. To filter elements you can call `select` or `reject`. For `ActiveRecord::Relation` you can chain `where` or `order` to it, as you said.

The difference is where the sorting and processing goes. For Array, it is done by the application; for Relation - by the database. The latter is usually faster, when there is more records. It is also more memory efficient.